# How to set Picture in Picture for Webview?

Tags: android, webview, picture-in-picture

I have tried this way

```
    @Override
    public void onUserLeaveHint () {
        PictureInPictureParams pip = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                .setAspectRatio(new Rational(16,9))
                .build();
        enterPictureInPictureMode(pip);
    }
```

Manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".ContentViewActivity"
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
    android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

The problem is the video from webview pauses and webview dose not maintain it's full screen

Comment: could you solve this problem?